# Should have different setup for Web development and Mobile development(Ionic)?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am planning to develop web & mobile application. Also planning to choose Ionic-Angular, SpringBoot, Postgresql. As all are freeware.

Before I proceed, I would like to clarify the below.

1. Should I develop Web app and Mobile app separately?(Two projects)
2. Can any software Replace Spring Boot(any open source even for commercial, especially for DB Connectivity/ User Authentication)?

Comment: I don't know about 2 but for 1-No, you can develop web app and mobile app using single project.

Comment: 1. You must decide this based on your requirements. Ionic will perform poorly in terms of heavy apps like games and graphic-based GUI.
2. Spring Boot is Server Side Technology, there are always other tools available to write your own web API, just choose the tool which you are comfortable with. Still alternatives can be: .Net Core API, Python Django or even PHP

Comment: If you choose to go with Ionic/Angular, either you create two separate apps and use in both of them the same logic, either consider using nx with xplat for creating a monorepo where both apps share the same services, models, etc.
nx: [link](https://nx.dev/)
xplat: [link](https://nstudio.io/xplat)

Comment: @RaghuramSadineni: How do we manage in single project, with any third party tool or using hidewhen?

Comment: you can write ui based on screen sizes and put conditions to display based on screen size.